# How do I find the area or perimeter of a rectangle using Functions?

Tags: function

On Program 9 - Functions - Coding Challenge, I have to Find the Area and Perimeter of a Rectangle using NotePad++. I know it's different compared to the area of a circle, but in order to find the area and perimeter of a rectangle, I need to create 2 Functions. My Program also has Comments on how to solve it (See my program below.). But my question is, how do I find the area or perimeter of a rectangle using Functions?

**My Javascript Program:**

```
function controller() {
        var type = document.getElementById("apBox").value;
        var length = document.getElementById("lengthBox").value;
        var width = document.getElementById("widthBox").value;
        type = type.toUpperCase();
        var result;
        var output;
        
        if (type = "A") //create a condition where you compare the type variable to the user's input for area. 
        {
            /*You will call a function that takes the length
            and width and returns the area and saves it to the result variable.
            2nd line of code will save the result along with some text to the output variable.
            */

        }
        else if (type = "P") //create a condition where you compare the type variable to the user's input for perimeter.
        {
            /*You will call a function that takes the length
            and width and returns the perimeter and saves it to the result variable.
            2nd line of code will save the result along with some text to the output variable.
            */
        }
        else 
        {
            //Create a line of code that catches all other input from the user. Basically an error message.
        }

        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=(output); //notice that the value in output will be displayed
    }
    
    //Create a function below that takes 2 parameters which are length and width and calculates the area of a rectangle.
    //This function will also return the area.
    
    
    
    //Create a function below that takes 2 parameters which are length and width and calculates the perimeter of a rectangle.
    //This function will also return the perimeter.
    
    
    
    function clearText() {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=("<br>");
        document.getElementById("apBox").value="";
        document.getElementById("lengthBox").value="";
        document.getElementById("widthBox").value="";
    }
```